# How to throw error when issue with mongoDB and PHP connection?

Tags: php, mongodb

In php and mysql we use `mysqli_error(connection);` to show error but how to show error while php mongoDB connection goes wrong. `$m = new MongoClient();`
please help..!

Comment: What did you tried ???

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MongoConnectionException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoconnectionexception.php) class..

This exception gets thrown when you have connection issues.

Comment: Thanks @raidenace